# Show event title on 'rendering:background' calendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I have my google calendar synched to Fullcalendar, and am rendering its events as 'background'

```
eventSources: [
      {
      googleCalendarId: 'calendarname@group.calendar.google.com',
      color: '#e7e7e7', 
      rendering: 'background'
      },
```

I would like to display the event's time as a block on top of the background color. (im in month view)

Comment: have you tried handling "eventRender" to see if you can add it back into the HTML from there?

Comment: It doesnt affect anything if the calendar is set to rendering: 'background' for me.

Using eventRender I should be able to detect if the event is allday and apply element.css('color', 'red'), but that just affects the blocks color, and not the cell's background color.

Comment: you never mentioned changing the background colour in the question...but for that you'd use the CSS "background-color" property. "color" affects the element's text colour. Anyway I've added an answer with a demo showing that you can do what you originally asked in the question quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "eventRender" callback you can set any text you like on the event's HTML element:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)
{
  if (event.allDay == false)
  {
     element.css("color", "red");
     element.css("font-weight", "bold");
     element.css("font-size", ".8em");
     element.text(event.start.format("HH:mm"));
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/18/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Sorry about the confusion, but im still trying to display the events time or title or anything when the calendar is set to rendering:background. Right now nothing else will display in the cell when its set to rendering:background (for month view).

Comment: for that just remove the `if (event.allDay == false)`...month view only shows background events which are marked as all day. Obviously in an allDay context, showing a time doesn't make much sense, but you could certainly display other info. I wrote my code like this this because in the question you specifically mentioned showing the time, which obviously only applies to non-all-day events.